# Unable to update comboBox from another comboBox

Tags: c#, combobox

```
private void tabControl1_Selected(object sender, TabControlEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.TabPage.Name == tabPage2.Name)
        {
            table = Items.Get();
            comboBox1.DataSource = table;
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Item_ID";
        }
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable temp = new DataTable();
        string text = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        temp = Color.Get(text);
        comboBox2.DataSource = temp;
        comboBox2.DisplayMember = "Color_Name";
        comboBox2.ValueMember = "Color_ID";
    }
```

I am trying to populate the comboBox1 as the tabpage open and then populate the comboBox2 based on the selectedText of comboBox1.

comboBox_SelectedIndexChange runs 2 times when tab changes but returns null every times.

Note: I have already appended event handler as the form initializes like,

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        tabControl1.Selected += new TabControlEventHandler(tabControl1_Selected);
        comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged;

        table = new DataTable();
        s = new Stock();
    }
```

Comment: What is `Color.Get(text)`? What is the `ValueMember` for comboBox1? Why do you need `DataTable temp = new DataTable()` if 2 lines down you do `temp =...`?

Comment: Actually it is user defined class `public DataTable Color.Get(string ItemID)` //return available colors of itemID passed. Contents of Datatable are **Color_ID** of type _int_ and **Color_Name** of type _string_ .

Comment: You can prevent code from running twice by private member `bool` variable that you set in `tabControl1_Selected` and read in `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged`. The only comment I have, you shouldn't name your types with the name of well-known system types such as `Color`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void tabControl1_Selected(object sender, TabControlEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.TabPage.Name == tabPage2.Name)
        {
            table = Items.Get();
            if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                //Update comboBox1 using table
                comboBox1.DataSource = table;
                comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Item_ID";

                //Using 1st row and 1st coloumn in function argument to get colors
                //Color.Get(string itemID) returns dataTable, which I used for comboBox2 DataSource
                comboBox2.DataSource = Color.Get(table.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString());
                comboBox2.ValueMember = "Color_ID";
                comboBox2.DisplayMember = "Color_Name";
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First there is a bug in

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable temp = new DataTable();
    string text = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    temp = Color.Get(text);
    comboBox2.DataSource = temp;
    comboBox2.DisplayMember = "Color_Name";
    comboBox2.ValueMember = "Color_ID";
}
```

code. You override value for datasource in line

```
temp = Color.Get(text);
```

I think it should be like:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable temp = new DataTable();
    string text = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    selectedColor = Color.Get(text);
    comboBox2.DataSource = temp;
    comboBox2.DisplayMember = "Color_Name";
    comboBox2.ValueMember = "Color_ID";
    comboBox2.SelectedItem = selectedColor;
}
```

I don't know contents of DataTable so instead of `comboBox2.SelectedItem` you may need to set `SelectedItem`, `SelectedText` or `SelectedValue` properties of `comboBox2`.

Answer (score 0):

Suspicious line here:

```
string text = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

You will get text variable filled with "YourNamespace.DataTable". If your function `Color.Get(text)` is expecting Item_ID of selected item as parameter, then you should change that line of code above to:

```
string text = ((DataTable)comboBox1.SelectedItem).Item_ID;
```

I assumed that DataTable is an object that have Item_ID property.